# best Graphical disk space explorer utility for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows-explorer, disk-space

what is the best disk space explorer utility for linux?

I want to see folder wise size graphically, which folder has taken how much disk space.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic but disk space and file usage can be quite different. Baobab, one of the answers, shows files under the root '/' and has no concept of multiple disks or free space. Something like gparted is good at showing overall disk stats but is useless for lower level detail. WinDirStat, and I *assume* KDirStat, show both disk based and file based information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Personally I like [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/).

[image: kdirstat screenshot]

Comment: Does the job ^-^. Running on gnome desktop the application used its KDE standards instead of trying to use my gnome equivalents. Though whadayaexpect. Great app for the job so long as Baobab doesn't add individual file visualization support.

Comment: Would be perfect, if it didn't want a hundred or two megs of KDE dependencies, not so good if you're not on KDE & don't want all it's stuff, generally counterproductive to increase disk usage that much while trying to reduce disk usage

Comment: It has been superseded by [QDirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat), which does not depend on KDE.

Answer (score 38):

Ubuntu default [Disk Usage Analyzer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab) (GNOME)

[image]

Comment: Also called Baobab.

Comment: baobab is awesome! (I wish it had the "delete permanently" option in addition to "move to trash")

Comment: baobab is painfully slow (unless you have <100k files and lots of time), qdirstat seems to work much better for me.

Answer (score 13):

[TreeSize for Unix](http://treesize.sourceforge.net/)

[Filelight](https://utils.kde.org/projects/filelight/) (KDE)

[xdiskusage](http://xdiskusage.sourceforge.net/)

While not the prettiest, [`ncdu`](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) works in a text-only terminal and does provide a simple graph of each entry.

Not at all graphical, but highly useful: [gt5](http://gt5.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: +1 for `ncdu`, it's very useful when connected to machines via `ssh`.

Comment: Awesome tool, but xdiskusage and specially `ncdu`

Comment: Noe that your filelight link redirects elsewear now.

Answer (score 6):

ncdu will be your friend its command line tool presents graphical presentation of you data structure.

Site reference: https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/man

You can install it using Ubuntu repository.

> root@slave1:~# apt-get install ncdu

Usage:

> root@slave1:~# ncdu -x /var/jenkins/

Comment: Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if the provided link(s) breaks please [edit] these details into your answer. That said, this question no longer meets this site's standards and will be closed, so there's little point in fixing this answer now...